# How to loop through an array an put create an array of objects using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to loop through an array elements and create an array of objects with its values.

below is the array example which comes from querying from an api.

```
const array = [
    "first",
    "second",
]
```

now i want to create an array of objects like below

```
const arr_obj = [
    {
         label: "first",
         value: "first",
     }
     {
         label: "second",
         value: "second",
      }
  ]
```

i have tried like below

```
const arr_obj = React.useMemo(() => {
    const output = arr.forEach(item => { //error
        return {
            label: item,
             value: item,
         }
     }, [arr]});
```

but this gives error arr could be possibly undefined or null and also i think this is not the way to create an array of objects with label, value pairs from the array elements.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array = [
  "first",
  "second",
]

const res = array.map(e => ({
  label: e,
  value: e
}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks how can i check if array is null or undefined before mapping? i get error object could be possibly null | undefined.

Comment: @stackuser You can wrap the `map` in an if statement: `if (array != null){ /* map */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this one?

```js
const array = [
  "first",
  "second",
]
let arr_obj = []
for (let i in array) {
  arr_obj.push({
    label: array[i],
    value: array[i],
  })
}
console.log(arr_obj)
```